# MVC In Html.Begin form need two buttons call different actions with all the values of the form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Frnds i want to submit data to two different controllers using two different buttons on one form and i want that both buttons call different actions and also provide all the values of the form to their respected controller.

Comment: Do you have jQuery in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with JavaScript like so:

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
    ... The Rest Of Your Form ...
    <input type="Submit" id="btn-1" name="btn-1" />
    <input type="Submit" id="btn-2" name="btn-2" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function(d) {
    var form = d.getElementsByTagName('form')[0],
        targetBtn;
    form.onsubmit = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        targetBtn = e.explicitOriginalTarget.id;

        //Set the form action based on the id of the button that submitted it
        if(targetBtn === 'btn-1') {
            form.action = '/foo';
        } else {
            form.action = '/bar'
        }

        //Submit your form
        form.submit();
    };
}(document));
```

All you need to do is make sure this code is placed after the from in the HTML markup or add it to a jQuery document.ready function.

Answer (score 0):

here is a good article that can help you accomplish what you want

http://blog.ashmind.com/2010/03/15/multiple-submit-buttons-with-asp-net-mvc-final-solution/

Comment: It's typically a good idea to include some of the content from the article rather than just a link to the article so that, if that link would disappear in the future, the answer can stand on its own.

Comment: @JasCav rightly so but i was not sure what to include and what not to its a short article. P.S the OP has not gone through the trouble of including any of the code he has tried so i also decided not to `:)`