# MVC3 JQuery-Ajax Search

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am trying to adapt the following code

```
$(“#artistSearch”).submit(function (event) {  
    event.preventDefault();  
    var form = $(this);  
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr(“action”),
        data: form.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function () {
        $(“#ajax-loader”).show();
    },
    complete: function () {
        $(“#ajax-loader”).hide();
    },
    error: searchFailed,
    success: function (data) {
        $(“#artistTemplate”).tmpl(data).appendTo(“#artist-list”);
    }
});
```

from [Professional ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-3.productCd-1118076583.html) to allow searching and returning data within the same form and ended up with the following:

On a separate script file

```
$(function () {

    $("#btnSearch").click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    var idno = $("#txtIdNo").value;

     $.ajax({
         url: "/Owner/Search",
         type: "POST",
         data: idno,
         datatype: "json",
         beforeSend: function () {
             $("#FullName").html("");
             $("#OwnerId").html("");
             $("#notFound").html("");
             $("#ajax-loader").show();
         },
         complete: function () {
             $("#ajax-loader").hide();
         },
         error: function () {
             $("#notFound").html("Sorry, no data returned."); ;
         },
         success: function (data) {
             $("#OwnerId").html(data.OwnerId);
             $("#FullName").html(data.FullName);
         }
     });
 });

});
```

On the Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SearchById(string idNo)
    {
        var owner = _ownerService.FindBy(x => x.IdNo == idNo);
        return  Json(owner);
    }
```

On the View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <p>
               Id No:
               <input type="text" name="txtIdNo"  />
               <input type="button" value="Search" name="btnSearch" />
               <label id="notFound"></label>
            </p> 
        @Html.Hidden("OwnerId")
       .
       .
       .

       <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Create" />
       </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

The reason I am using 
    
within the view is to avoid two submit buttons within the same form because I realized the form was validating after clicking on the search button.

I have also looked at the suggested similar questions before asking with no avail.

I have been unable to make the above work  and would appreciate any help offered.

I am a newbie to MVC3 and JQuery

Comment: if "The reason I am using within the view is to avoid two submit buttons within the same form because I realized the form was validating after clicking on the search button." is the reason ... have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9022708/1182982

Comment: @Yasser I have bookmarked the referenced article and will go through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**jquery ID Selector (“#id”) - Selects a single element with the given id attribute.**

You are using jquery ID Selector, but you donot have the id attribute on the from elements.

Add id attribute to your form elements.

```
<input type="text" name="txtIdNo"  />
<input type="button" value="Search" name="btnSearch" />

to 

<input type="text" id="txtIdNo" name="txtIdNo"  />
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" name="btnSearch" />
```

Edit the jQuery ajax function: **data: {idNo:idno}**

```
$.ajax({
         url: "/Owner/Search",
         type: "POST",
         data: {idNo:idno},
         datatype: "json",
         .........
     });
 });
```

Comment: I have added the ID selectors and at least now the controller is being invoked. The only issue I have is a null value is being passed to the controller.

Comment: I have updated data from data: to data:{idNo:idno} but still passes null value. I also tried changing  var idno = $("#txtIdNo").value; to var idno = $("#txtIdNo").val(); with no success.

Comment: Used Fiddler to clear Cache and now it works. Thanks to all those who assisted me in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using the form (going grabbing the field value you're searching for and sending it to a controller action) you can avoid the submission by making the button;

```
<button type="button">Create</button>
```

or

```
<input type="button" value="Create" />
```

This would be the quickest way of avoiding the postback.

You can also look at ajaxSubmit (jQuery plugin) or you can use Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm (but those both require a little more time)